# Unable to Mouse Hover through xpath

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, mouseover

I'm using to following code to hover over an element

```
Webelement el=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/app-root/div/app-root/div/app-admin-app/app-header/div/div[3]/a"));
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(el).perform();
```

but it is not working.

The HTML of element as below:

```
<a _ngcontent-c4="" class="ui label " style="width:100%">
  <img _ngcontent-c4="" 
       class="ui right spaced avatar image" 
       src="assets/images/avatar.png">admin </a>
```

Comment: html as shown below,<a _ngcontent-c4="" class="ui label " style="width:100%">
      <img _ngcontent-c4="" class="ui right spaced avatar image" src="assets/images/avatar.png">admin
    </a>

Comment: please provide me the customized xpath

Comment: If xpath `//a[contains(. 'admin')]` can find only one and exact element, try it in your code. And in general, the mouse hover effect very easy broken by things. like when mouse hover on element, but the page is refreshing , or partial area of page is refresh/loading. So it's better to make sure your mouse hover when  the page is `stable` enough.

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* the element is a *Angular* element so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* and then *Mouse Hover* as follows :

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
WebElement elem = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@class='ui label']/img[@class='ui right spaced avatar image' and @src='assets/images/avatar.png']")));
act.moveToElement(elem).perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `JavascriptExecutor` class for performing the same Hover Over Functionality:

import the JavascriptExecutor Class:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
```

And use this Method instead of `Actions` Class:

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a/img[contains(@src,'assets/images/avatar.png')]"));

String mouseOver = "var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');" +
                    "evObj.initMouseEvent(\"mouseover\",true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);" +
                    "arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj);";

((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(mouseOver, element);
```

Try this out and Let me know if it works for you.